# CSS only tooltip getting out of div or screen

Tags: html, css, tooltip

Trying to create a CSS-ONLY tooltip. But the problem is, when the tooltip containing word is at extreme left or right, the tooltip gets out of screen resulting a lesser display of tooltip text.
How can I solve this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9U1Ml.png)

overflow x of body is hidden (Mandatory)

Following is my CSS and HTML:

````
[data-ToolTip] {
  position: relative
}

[data-ToolTip]:before {
  content: '';
  display: none;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  border-top-color: #000;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 8;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

[data-ToolTip]:after {
  display: none;
  content: attr(data-ToolTip);
  position: absolute;
  top: -35px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 0px 8px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 9;
  font-size: 13px;
  height: 28px;
  line-height: 28px;
  line-break: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

[data-ToolTip]:hover:before,
[data-ToolTip]:hover:after {
  display: block;
}```

And HTML:


```<p style="text-align: right;"><span data-ToolTip="Version Control System">VCS</span></p>
````

Comment: Try right: 0 instead of left:0 on [data-ToolTip]:after

Comment: From what I understand, the problem is more related to your container than to your tooltip itself. We will need more info about your HTML and CSS in a snippet for example.

Comment: No, It is not a container issue, position is absolute, and if I try right 0 instead of left 0, what would i do if the word is on extreme left???